# spring boot, problema mapeando vista con controlador sencillo

Tags: spring, spring-boot

He iniciado una aplicación con *Spring Boot*, *Generate maven project* with *Java 1.8* and *Spring Boot 2.0.3*. He creado un simple controlador y una vista y no me la mapea. ¿Hay que tocar algo? ¿algún application propertie?

Tengo la vista en templates (`holamundo.html`) y mi controlador:

```
package controladores;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller; import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping; import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping; @Controller @RequestMapping("/say")

public class holamundoController {

    @GetMapping("/holamundo")

    public String HolaMundo(){

        return "holamundo";
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

sería bueno que postearas algo de tu codigo para ver que podría fallar.
De primera instancia, cuando se trabaja con Spring boot se necesita principalmente esto:

-Tener tu CLASE controladora (recordar que se debe anotar @Controller para indicarlo).

-Tener tu vista según sea en HTML o con JSP (si es HTML con motor de plantilla Thymeleaf debes colocarlo en /resources/templates, si es JSP es normal con webapp).

-En tu clase controladora, debes apuntar con un @RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.GET) donde en VALUE iría la ruta con el cual deseas acceder a la pagina -localhost../test- o también es posible con @GetMapping("/test") seguido del esqueleto de tu método.

-Por último, debes retornar el nombre de la pagina.

Ejemplo:

```
@GetMapping("/test")
public String test{

...
..
return "test"
}
```

Para el caso de thymeleaf no necesitas especifical el .html

Saludos.

Comment: hola, gracias por responder, tengo la vista en templetes (holamundo.html) y mi controlador:package controladores;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/say")
public class holamundoController {
 @GetMapping("/holamundo")
 public String HolaMundo(){
  return "holamundo";
 }

}

Comment: Que tal, solamente es eso.
Intenta crear un nuevo proyecto, me sucedió que no lo mapeaba porque produje error con el mismo  nombre de la clase y el @Controller, quizás te pasó lo mismo.

Comment: Quizás a la hora de que estabas probando tu proyecto produjo algun errorr (me pasó eso al llamarle Controller a mi clase y @Controller a la anotación y aunque cambié el nombre de la clase, el conflicto quedó así que no funcionaba y tuve que volver a crear el proyecto.

Intenta lo siguiente: 
-Crea un nuevo proyecto
-Crea tu HTML en templates con nombre test
Crea tu clase Controladora
-HAz la anotación ARROBAController, crea tu metodo básico tipo ARROBAGetMapping("/") 
public String test(){
return "test"
}

Comment: ok gracias, probaré a ver!

Answer (score -1):

Tienes que anotar tu controlador con @Controller

```
@Controller
public class HolamundoController {

    @GetMapping("/holamundo")
    public String holaMundo(){

       return "holamundo";
    }

}
```

Tambien recuerda que las clases tienen que empezar en Mayusculas y los métodos en minusculas.

Saludos